# bootstrap tabs with flotchart

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, flot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [loading flot chart in jquery tab workaround doesn’t completely fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976958/loading-flot-chart-in-jquery-tab-workaround-doesnt-completely-fix-the-issue)

I am trying to load two flot.js charts into two different tabs. I am using the tabs from the twitter bootstrap framework. The first flot chart loads fine on the first tab (since the tab is visible), but for the second flot chart, it does not render on the second "hidden/inactive" tab. I have looked and searched everywhere for a solution, its almost 6am, been up all night trying to find a solution for this. Did anyone know of any solution to this?

Thank!

Comment: Can you set up an example jsFiddle?  I started one here: http://jsfiddle.net/6f2Vr/ but can not recreate your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I just figured it out! Flot requires the size of the placeholder to be set before creating the plot. I guess I just needed the sleep :)