# Calling multiple Jquery plot using tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, flot

I have two Jquery plot real-time graphs, once the first is loaded, if I click on "graph 2" tab, the second graph is called but, not being loaded in the div where the first graph was previously loaded.
Any help?

**jquery**

```
<script>
var page = baseurl+'/ajaxcall.php';
function get_data(vara,div)
{
    $(div).css("display","block");
    $.post(page, 
    {   
        posta : vara        
    },
    function(data)
    {
        $(div).html(data);
    },'text');
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="toolbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="get_data('callgraph1','#divid')">graph 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="get_data('callgraph2','#divid')">graph 2</a>
 </div>
 <div id="divid"></div>
```

Comment: are you getting any error.... check your console

Comment: no error at all. The page needs to be refreshed, so using tab is useless in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading flot chart in jquery tab workaround doesn't completely fix the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976958/loading-flot-chart-in-jquery-tab-workaround-doesnt-completely-fix-the-issue)

Comment: it may work by using iframes with complete html body and js files.