# flot displaying correct date figures on xaxis using time

Tags: flot

I have 13 weeks of data which i want to display as bar graph. I want the dates to start from Monday each week. I have managed to get 13 weeks to display on xaxis and 13 bar lines to display. I cannot get the dates to start from Mondays and line up with the bar line.

```js
var datasets = [{"label":"Amend Existing Report","data":[{"0":1446422400000,"1":0},{"0":1447027200000,"1":0},{"0":1447632000000,"1":0},{"0":1448236800000,"1":0},{"0":1448841600000,"1":0},{"0":1449446400000,"1":1},{"0":1450051200000,"1":0},{"0":1450656000000,"1":0},{"0":1451260800000,"1":0},{"0":1451865600000,"1":0},{"0":1452470400000,"1":0},{"0":1453075200000,"1":1},{"0":1453680000000,"1":1},{"0":1454284800000,"1":0}],"idx":0},{"label":"Investigate Report Problem","data":[{"0":1446422400000,"1":1},{"0":1447027200000,"1":0},{"0":1447632000000,"1":2},{"0":1448236800000,"1":4},{"0":1448841600000,"1":0},{"0":1449446400000,"1":1},{"0":1450051200000,"1":0},{"0":1450656000000,"1":2},{"0":1451260800000,"1":0},{"0":1451865600000,"1":0},{"0":1452470400000,"1":0},{"0":1453075200000,"1":5},{"0":1453680000000,"1":0},{"0":1454284800000,"1":0}],"idx":1},{"label":"New Request (One Off Report)","data":[{"0":1446422400000,"1":0},{"0":1447027200000,"1":0},{"0":1447632000000,"1":1},{"0":1448236800000,"1":0},{"0":1448841600000,"1":0},{"0":1449446400000,"1":0},{"0":1450051200000,"1":0},{"0":1450656000000,"1":0},{"0":1451260800000,"1":0},{"0":1451865600000,"1":0},{"0":1452470400000,"1":0},{"0":1453075200000,"1":0},{"0":1453680000000,"1":1},{"0":1454284800000,"1":0}],"idx":2},{"label":"New Request (Regular Report)","data":[{"0":1446422400000,"1":4},{"0":1447027200000,"1":0},{"0":1447632000000,"1":2},{"0":1448236800000,"1":2},{"0":1448841600000,"1":0},{"0":1449446400000,"1":1},{"0":1450051200000,"1":0},{"0":1450656000000,"1":0},{"0":1451260800000,"1":1},{"0":1451865600000,"1":1},{"0":1452470400000,"1":0},{"0":1453075200000,"1":3},{"0":1453680000000,"1":2},{"0":1454284800000,"1":0}],"idx":3},{"label":"Other","data":[{"0":1446422400000,"1":0},{"0":1447027200000,"1":0},{"0":1447632000000,"1":2},{"0":1448236800000,"1":4},{"0":1448841600000,"1":2},{"0":1449446400000,"1":0},{"0":1450051200000,"1":2},{"0":1450656000000,"1":0},{"0":1451260800000,"1":0},{"0":1451865600000,"1":0},{"0":1452470400000,"1":3},{"0":1453075200000,"1":0},{"0":1453680000000,"1":3},{"0":1454284800000,"1":0}],"idx":4},{"label":"Special Events","data":[{"0":1446422400000,"1":0},{"0":1447027200000,"1":0},{"0":1447632000000,"1":0},{"0":1448236800000,"1":1},{"0":1448841600000,"1":0},{"0":1449446400000,"1":3},{"0":1450051200000,"1":1},{"0":1450656000000,"1":0},{"0":1451260800000,"1":0},{"0":1451865600000,"1":0},{"0":1452470400000,"1":0},{"0":1453075200000,"1":0},{"0":1453680000000,"1":0},{"0":1454284800000,"1":0}],"idx":5}];

var options = {"legend":{"position":"ne","noColumns":6},"yaxis":{"min":0},"xaxis":{"mode":"time","timeformat":"%d %b","tickSize":[7,"day"],"min":1446163200000,"max":1454284800000},"grid":{"clickable":true,"hoverable":true},"series":{"stack":true,"bars":{"show":true,"barWidth":181440000.00000003}}};

$.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);


$("#CAGraph").bind("plothover",function(event, pos, item) {
  if (item) {
   // console.log(event);
   // console.log(pos);
   //console.log(item);
   var epoch = new Date(item.datapoint[0]);
   var percent = item.datapoint[1] - item.datapoint[2];
   $("#tooltip").html(
     moment(epoch).format("DD MMM") + " - "
       + item.series.label + " " + (percent)
       + "<br>Total: " + item.datapoint[1]).css({
    top : item.pageY - 25,
    left : item.pageX + 10
   }).fadeIn(200);
  } else {
   $("#tooltip").hide();
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.8.5/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
<div id ="choices_CAGraph">

</div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:910px;height:400px">
  <div id='tooltip' style="position:absolute;display:none"></div>
```

My min and max calulcations for xaxis

```
min : (new Date(moment().subtract(14,'week').day(0).subtract(2,"day").subtract(6,"hour").format('YYYY/MM/DD')).getTime()),
        max : (new Date(moment().subtract(1,'week').startOf('isoweek').format('YYYY/MM/DD')).getTime())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the automatic tick generator from Flot does not what you want, you can always manually define the ticks (here by getting them from the data):

```
var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
  ticks.push(datasets[0].data[i][0]);
}
```

After also specifiying `align: 'center'` for the bars the bars and x axis ticks are now aligned.

PS: Your data has 14 data points, not 13. I also adjusted the max value for the x axis so the last bar is visible.

```js
var datasets = [{
  "label": "Amend Existing Report",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 0
}, {
  "label": "Investigate Report Problem",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 5
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 1
}, {
  "label": "New Request (One Off Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 2
}, {
  "label": "New Request (Regular Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 3
}, {
  "label": "Other",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 4
}, {
  "label": "Special Events",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 5
}];

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
  ticks.push(datasets[0].data[i][0]);
}

var options = {
  "legend": {
    "position": "ne",
    "noColumns": 6
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "min": 0
  },
  "xaxis": {
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%d %b",
    //    "tickSize": [7, "day"],
    ticks: ticks,
    "min": 1446163200000,
    "max": 1454544000000 // 1454284800000
  },
  "grid": {
    "clickable": true,
    "hoverable": true
  },
  "series": {
    "stack": true,
    "bars": {
      "show": true,
      "barWidth": 181440000.00000003,
      align: 'center'
    }
  }
};

$.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);

$("#CAGraph").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
  if (item) {
    // console.log(event);
    // console.log(pos);
    //console.log(item);
    var epoch = new Date(item.datapoint[0]);
    var percent = item.datapoint[1] - item.datapoint[2];
    $("#tooltip").html(
      moment(epoch).format("DD MMM") + " - " + item.series.label + " " + (percent) + "<br>Total: " + item.datapoint[1]).css({
      top: item.pageY - 25,
      left: item.pageX + 10
    }).fadeIn(200);
  } else {
    $("#tooltip").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.8.5/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="choices_CAGraph"></div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:910px;height:400px"></div>
<div id='tooltip' style="position:absolute;display:none"></div>
```

Comment: I have managed to add the ticks and and align the bars with axis. just need some help with calculating the max value

Comment: Use half the difference between the values and subtract that from the first value for min and add it to the last value for max. That looks good in the chart.

Comment: I noticed when generating on 2 different tabs the 1st tab it aligns fine but 2nd tab the alignment is off?

Comment: Generating charts in inactive / hidden tabs can cause problems. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976958/loading-flot-chart-in-jquery-tab-workaround-doesnt-completely-fix-the-issue) for a solution.